Determining the minimum value of the function $f(x, y) = \frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x}$ with $x, y\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$.
I want to conclude that the minimum value of the function $f(x, y) = \frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x}$ with $x > 0, y > 0$ is 2 obtained along the line $x = y$, but I seem to be a bit rusty with my multivariate calculus. One can compute zeros of the partial derivatives of $f$ show that the zeros are obtained with $x = y$. So if both eigenvalues of the Hessian matrix of $f$ at $(x, y)$ were to be positive, then this point would be a local minimum. But at $x = y$, one of the eigenvalues if zero and the other one is $\frac{4}{x^2}$. If I recall correctly, this means that the Hessian of $f$ at $(x, y)$ is positive semi-definite, which is not sufficient to conclude the claim about the minimum?
Partials of $f$ are
$$\partial_x f(x, y) = \frac{1}{y} - \frac{y}{x^2}$$
$$\partial_y f(x, y) = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{x}{y^2}$$
and the Hessian of $f$ is
$$Hf(x, y) = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{2y}{x^3} & -\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{y^2}\\ -\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{y^2} & \frac{2x}{y^3}\end{bmatrix}$$
So what can I do instead?

You can just prove that the minimum of $t\mapsto t+\frac{1}{t}$ is $2$.

$f(x,y) \ge 2$ and equality holds when $x=y=1$.

We have following equivalences
$$(x-y)^2 \geq 0 \iff x^2 + y^2 \geq 2xy \stackrel{x,y>0}{\iff} \frac{x^2+y^2}{xy}\geq 2 \iff \frac xy + \frac yx \geq 2.$$
Using the same equivalences, just with equality instead of inequality, you can see that $\frac xy + \frac yx = 2$ if and only if $(x-y)^2 = 0$, i.e. $x = y$.
Therefore, $2$ is the minimum and it is achieved when $x=y$.

This might seem somewhat ad hoc, but if we substitute $x = \sqrt a$ and $y = \sqrt b$, we get (a proof of) AM-GM inequality $\frac{a+b}{2} \geq \sqrt{ab}$.

You could remark that: $\forall x, y\in \Bbb R, f(x,y) = g(\frac x y)$, where $g:\Bbb R^*\to\Bbb R^*$ is defined by $g(x)=x+\frac 1 x$.
Now if $f$ has a minimum at $(x_0, y_0)$, then $g$ will have a minimum at $\frac {x_0}{y_0}$, and the reciprocal is also true:
$$f(x,y) >= f(x_0, y_0)\iff g\left(\frac x y\right) >= g\left(\frac {x_0}{y_0}\right)$$.
That means that it is enough to study $g$ for its minimum. The derivative is
$g'(x) = 1 - \frac 1 {x^2}$. If $x_0$ is a minimum for $g$, then $g'(x_0) = 0$.
$$g(x_0) = 0\iff 1-\frac 1{x^2} = 0\iff x^2 - 1 = 0\iff x_0 = 1 {\text { or }}  x_0=-1$$
As we only consider positive values for $f$, we can restrict the analysis to positive values for $g$ too. We have $0<x<1\implies g'(x) <0$ and $x>1\implies g'(x) >0$.
So we have showed that $g$ has a minimum at $1$, and that $g(1) = 2$. We can conclude that $f(x,y)$ is minimum when $x=y$:
$$\forall x, y, z\in \Bbb R_+^*, f(x, y)>=f(z,z) = 2$$

Another angle:
$z:=x/y;$
Consider
$f(z):=2 (\dfrac{e^z+e^{-z}}{2}) =$
$2\cosh z. $
